# Light Map projection

Tags: wpf, 3d, textures, shader

What i'm trying to do is making a "light projector" with visible ray(like with fog) also called volumetric light;

and which project a image (bitmap) ;

Because i would like to keep this project connected with a wpf application ( to get brush, position, rotation from data), i've choose to use WPF 3D

But it seem that WPF can't handle light projection or render ray.

So to do that, i have extruded each pixel of my source bitmap into a polygon colored by a solidColorBrush of the pixel color.

and keep the pixel order with (x,y) position.

For performance issue, i've set all the bitmaps to 32x32 px ( 1024 polygon for only one light !!)

But the result is too pixelated as you can see on the picture.

Moreover, it probably take much memory for nothing ...

my question is, how can i make it smooth or even rethink the extrusion system to optimize performance ...

Is any other tehnology that can be integrated into a wpf application and do that better or easier ?

Thanks, and sorry my English is pretty bad ...
[alt text http://www.visualdmx.fr/pic_example.png](http://www.visualdmx.fr/pic_example.png)